# Best way to sort posts with different types by distance

Tags: customization, order, sort

I'm working on a project that I need to

- We have x posts, 1 Sponsored (custom meta field), unlimited paid, unlimited free posts (these are types of posts)
- We need to show 1 sponsored at top, unlimited paid after it and unlimited free after paid
- We need to order all of them by distance to area user selected
- Each post has location stored in database attached to it

**Question #1:**

Currently I made 3 different queries with 3 different $args:

```
 $args_sponsored = array(
                        'post_type' => array('le_place'),
                        'posts_per_page' => '1',
                        'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'le_place_category',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => array($theCat)
                            )
                        ),
                        'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'key' => 'entry_type',
                                'value' => 'sponsored',
                            )
                        )
                    );

                      $args_paid = array(
                        'post_type' => array('le_place'),
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'order' => 'DESC',
                        'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'le_place_category',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => array($theCat)
                            )
                        ), 
                        'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'key' => 'entry_type',
                                'value' => array('paid'),
                            )
                        )
                    );


                    $args_free = array(
                        'post_type' => array('le_place'),
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'order' => 'DESC',
                        'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'le_place_category',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => array($theCat)
                            )
                        ), 
                        'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'key' => 'entry_type',
                                'value' => array('free'),
                            )
                        )
                    );
```

**and not sure this affect performance! is that a wrong method?**

**Question #2:**
How can I sort them by distance after getting all posts and then show them?

**sortByDistance($postsPaid); // how can I get custom fields of post objects?**

```
 $postsPaid = $queryPaid->get_posts();
                          sortByDistance($postsPaid); // how can I get custom fields of post objects? 


                            $placeLocation= get_field('location');
                               $longPlace =$placeLocation['lng'];

                         $latPlace = $placeLocation['lat'];



 function getDistance($lat2, $long2, $lat1, $long1) {
                        $R = 6378137; // Earth’s mean radius in meter
                        $dLat = rad($lat2 - $lat1);
                        $dLong = rad($long2 - $long1);

                      $a = sin($dLat / 2) * sin($dLat / 2) +
                                cos(rad($lat1)) * cos(rad($lat2)) *
                                sin($dLong / 2) * sin($dLong / 2);
                        $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1 - $a));
                        $d = $R * $c; // in meter

                        return intval((ceil($d) / 1000) * 0.621371); // returns the distance in Miles
                 };
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I added distance as custom field to allow me order them using wp_query orderby method!

```
 function    add_distance_as_customfield($posts){

       $longDest = $_GET['lng'];
                    $latDest = $_GET['ltd'];
      foreach ($posts as $post) {
           $placeLocation= get_field('location',$post->ID);
                               $longPlace =$placeLocation['lng'];

                         $latPlace = $placeLocation['lat'];
                         $distance=getDistance($latDest,$longDest,$latPlace,$longPlace);

                         if ( ! add_post_meta($post->ID, "distance", $distance,true ) ) { 
   update_post_meta( $post->ID, "distance", $distance );
}

      }
 }
```